# Best way of creating a user profile in Java

Tags: java

Right now I have a one class program that runs a bank app.

I come from a JS background and new to Java.

I essentially create a:

```
User username = new User(Double startingMoney, 
String fName, String lName, String userName, String passWord);
```

Then you would do things like:

```
username.setBalance(Double balanceAmt); or username.getBalance();
```

Issue is, I'm not sure how to name the Object. I want my program to allow the user to register a new user account, and make whatever the username they have, be the name of the Object.

In JS you can use a String as the object variable name.

I'm not even sure if this is the right way to go about creating a new user. I'm not sure how I would even reference the specific object later on, to set the balance for the user.

IE: I have two users... thus two user objects... one john and one betty.

If betty was logged in currently, i'm not sure how i'd call betty.setBalance(20.00);

Any suggestions or direction? Thanks.

Comment: Probably what you want to do is checkout some existing user-management frameworks (like Apache Shiro). If you want to write that yourself, you have to do some reading about user Sessions, Authorization and Authentication, Cryptography etc. and because it's a bank app, you have to consider floating point operations precision.

Comment: I suppose I should have stated that this was an amateur final project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is using a Map. Where you would use the name as a key and the value would be an User object.

```
Map <String, User> users = new Hashmap<String, User>();
users.put("betty", new User(...));
users.get("betty").setBalance(20.00);
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'll just try all of this next semester and leave my app as is.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks a lot!
I did currentUser = jtfUsername.getText(); to track which user was logged in. Then did your users.put(currentUser) and users.get(currentUser) to make users and get info from them.

Answer (score 2):

A class User should be made. usual setters and getters can be made. but to instantiate as you asked you can just give the parameters in the argument while instantiating the object. I've added 2 constructers for the class as an example.

```
     public class User
{
    private double startingMoney;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private static int count = 0; // number of objects in memory

    // initialize user, add 1 to static count and
     // output String indicating that constructor was called
     public User( String first, String last )
     {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;

        count++; // increment static count of Users
        System.out.printf( "User constructor: %s %s; count = %d\n",
           firstName, lastName, count );
     } // end User constructor


     private double startingMoney;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;


     //another constructer 
     public User( Double sMoney, String first, String last, String name, String pass)
     {
        startingMoney = sMoney
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        username = name;
        password = pass;

        count++; // increment static count of Users
        System.out.printf( "User constructor: %s %s; count = %d\n",
           firstName, lastName, count );
     } // end User constructor


     // subtract 1 from static count when garbage
     // collector calls finalize to clean up object;
     // confirm that finalize was called
     protected void finalize()
     {
        count--; // decrement static count of users
        System.out.printf( "User finalizer: %s %s; count = %d\n",
           firstName, lastName, count );
     } // end method finalize

   // set first name
     public String setFirstName(String firstName)
     {
        this.firstName = firstName;
     } // end method setFirstName

     // set last name
     public String setLastName(String lastName)
     {
        this.lastName = lastName;
     } // end method setLastName

    // set user name
     public String setUserName(String name)
     {
        this.username = name;
     } // end method setUserName

     // set password
     public String setPassword(String password)
     {
        this.password = password;
     } // end method setPassword






     public String getStartingName()
     {
        return startingName;
     } // end method getstartingName


    // get username
     public String getUserName()
     {
        return username;
     } // end method getUserName

     // get password
     public String getPassword()
     {
        return password;
     } // end method getPassword

    // get first name
     public String getFirstName()
     {
        return firstName;
     } // end method getFirstName

     // get last name
     public String getLastName()
     {
        return lastName;
     } // end method getLastName

     // static method to get static count value
     public static int getCount()              
     {                                         
        return count;                          
     } // end method getCount

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this would allow me to have multiple users. Seems like everytime I would create a new user, it would just override the previous users settings.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class first, then create two objects for that class.

```
class User {

//Constructor
User(Double startingMoney, String fName, String lName, String userName, String passWord) {
this.startingMoney=startingMoney;
this.fName=fName;
this.lName=lName; 
this.userName=userName;
this.passWord=passWord;
}
double startingMoney;
String fName;
String lName; 
String userName;
String passWord;
}


User john = new User(..Values.); //pass arguments related to john
User betty= new User(..Values.); //pass arguments related to betty

john.getLName();  
betty.setPassword("pass");


in java you cant create a runtime variable; better do this way
whenever user is arrived; use a Map
Map.add("userName", new User(...Values..)); //userName as key
then get that object like Map.get("userName")
```